# Error when creating context menus in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm getting the following error. The extension is working fine as I want it to but what's with the error?

[image: Extension Error]

Answer (score 1):

Context items persist between extension reloads - something not very obvious.

So you're getting this when this code is executed a second time.

A common pattern is clear-then-register:

```
chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
  chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);
  // Add more
});
```

If you're using an Event page (`persistent: false` background page), you probably don't want to execute that every time the page is woken up; wrap it in `chrome.runtime.onStartup` or even `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` (to register once per update).

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the menu to the permissions-part of your manifest.json?
More info can be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus).

Comment: The permissions have the following.  "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "storage",
      "notifications",
      "contextMenus"
  ]

Comment: @NoobCoder meaby this helps [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326994/issues-with-content-menu-and-opening-tabs-chrome-extension)?